# Got "expected string or bytes-like object" while tokenizing series of strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

I've got a series with a really messy strings, which I believe are *actual* strings:

```
text = data['MESSAGE'] #pandas.core.series.Series
text
0       Linux version 5.8.0-2parrot1-amd64 (team@parro...
1       Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.8.0-2parro...
2       x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 ...
3       x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE ...
4       x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX ...
                              ...                        
3512    pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for use...
3513    (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null ...
3514    pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for use...
3515        root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/void ; USER=r...
3516    pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for use...
Name: MESSAGE, Length: 3517, dtype: object
```

```
text.apply(lambda x: type(x))
0       <class 'str'>
1       <class 'str'>
2       <class 'str'>
3       <class 'str'>
4       <class 'str'>
            ...      
3512    <class 'str'>
3513    <class 'str'>
3514    <class 'str'>
3515    <class 'str'>
3516    <class 'str'>
Name: MESSAGE, Length: 3517, dtype: object
```

I tried to tokenize them row by row withTreebankWordTokenizer like:

```
text.apply(lambda x: TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(x))
```

```
text.apply(lambda row: TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize((str(sentence)) for sentence in text))
```

```
tokens = [TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text[i] for i in range(len(text)))]
```

But always got "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Comment: Check whether you have NaN value or not in the column.
You can check it with df["MESSAGE"].isna().sum()

Comment: @hasanyaman zero

Comment: Another guess: check whether you have string with zero length:
min(df["MESSAGE"].str.len())

Comment: Min length is 8, @hasanyaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons I dont understand, I had to convert my rows to a string. Simple `tokenize(str(x)))` without 'for' loop did the thing.